# How to convert accented chars to html in php?

Tags: php, html

I have foreign language strings stored in utf8. When displaying them, I want them to be transform in such a way that accented chars become their html counterparts, e.g. `é` becomes `&eacute;`

However I phrase my search, all I can find is `htmlentities()` which does not do it.

Comment: Please explain why you need to do this. If you generate UTF-8-encoded HTML, you can just output your UTF-8 characters.

Comment: Well, ok then. This just doesn't seem the right thing to do.

Comment: Apart from that, if you really wanted to convert to entities then `htmlentities` would indeed be it. Why do you think the opposite?

Comment: Mine worked just fine. `ãçéÿ` => `&atilde;&ccedil;&eacute;&yuml;`. Of course you will only see this if you peek at the source-code.

Comment: Trying to convert an utf8-encoded accented string with `htmlentities` returns an empty string.

Comment: Anyway, if @jeyk is correct, I take his comment as an answer.

Comment: Well then what you are not seeing is that `htmlentities` takes 3 parameters. Take a look at its manual and you will see you can input any character encoding to it, as long as you are specific about it: http://www.php.net/htmlentities

Comment: For instance `htmlentities(utf8_encode("ãçéÿ"), 0, 'UTF-8')` <-- works.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure you're properly specifying the encoding when you call [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

The documentation shows that it defaults to `'UTF-8'`, but if you read down a bit further, you'll see that that's new as of PHP 5.4. If you're using an older version, the default is actually `'ISO-8859-1'`, and you'll need to make sure you explicitly specify it as `'UTF-8'` instead of relying on the default behaviour.

```
htmlentities($string, 0, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: There are cases when you want to generate entities for accented characters (à ,è, ì, ò, ù, ...) but want to preserve HTML code (so do not excape "<" and ">" and avoid escaping already escaped entities. In those cases, you can use this code:  
`$string = str_replace(array("&lt;", "&gt;"), array("<", ">"), htmlentities($string, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8', FALSE));`  
This code is compatible with PHP >= 5.2.3

Comment: This answer is what I was really looking for!  Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

I found this is a very simple solution to this problem.

The first part tries to encode the text. If the $output returns a blank string, then the value is utf8 encoded and then the html entities are created.

```
$output = htmlentities($value, 0, "UTF-8");
if ($output == "") {
    $output = htmlentities(utf8_encode($value), 0, "UTF-8");
}
```

Example:

```
Montréal
```

Output:

```
Montr&eacute;al
```

Answer (score 2):

This was posted as a comment on another answer, but was exactly what I needed so I'm posting it as an answer on its own:

> There are cases when you want to generate entities for accented
> characters (à ,è, ì, ò, ù, ...) but want to preserve HTML code (so do
> not excape "<" and ">" and avoid escaping already escaped entities. In
> those cases, you can use this code:

```
$string = str_replace(array("&lt;", "&gt;"), array("<", ">"), htmlentities($string, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8', FALSE));
```

> This code is compatible with PHP >= 5.2.3

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17624909/how-to-convert-accented-chars-to-html-in-php#comment58948867_17625068))